# Receive data via uart for pic16F788 :mikroC

Tags: serial-port, pic, mikroc

I've written the java code to send data to pic via serial port and now I need to program the microcontroller to read the data and make PortD.RD6=1 if the it receives 1 and PortD.RD6=0 if it receives 0. I've tried this code but I get many errors .
This is my first mikroC program so I really don't know how to manage these errors.

```
char output[1];
unsigned short i;
 void main(){
 TRISD = 0x01;
 i = 0;
UART1_Init(9600);
while (1) {
if (UART1_Data_Ready()==1) {
i = UART1_Read(); // read the received data
ByteToStr(i, output);
if (output = "1" ) // this is where I get the error 
{PortD.RD6=1;}
else {  PortD.RD6=0;}

}}}
```

Comment: you use `output = "1"` instead of `output == "1"`

Comment: I've already tried that but still not working

Answer (score 2):

One error that I can spot is that `ByteToStr` returns three characters so it is probably overwriting other memory areas and giving an undefined result. You don't need to do that conversion you can simply read a byte into a `char` and do a comparison directly on that as follows:

```
void main()
{
    char c;

    TRISD = 0x01;
    UART1_Init(9600);
    while (1) {
        if (UART1_Data_Ready()) {
            c = UART1_Read();
            if (c == '1')
                PortD.RD6=1;
            else 
                PortD.RD6=0;
        }
    }
}
```